# Getting vba script to automatically calculate a range from a cell with multiple values

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba and have an issue that I hope someone can help me out with and please explain what each step is for me grasp an understanding.  I want to make it where I take a set of values in one cell and paste it in the other the thing about it is these are ip addresses with specific masks.  Say for instance a cell has 192.168.1.0/30, I want it to go to the next sheet and automatically convert the range to be 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.1.1 below it and onward.  I need it to detect whether or not it is /29 or /28 also and automatically fill in the column until it reaches the amount of addresses that are for the range. Also there might be instances where it will look like this:

192.168.1.0/30
192.168.5.25
192.168.6.120/28,192.168.6.0/29

and I want it to be like this basically on the next sheet

192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.5.25
192.168.6.120
192.168.6.121
192.168.6.122
192.168.6.123
192.168.6.124
192.168.6.125
192.168.6.126
192.168.6.127
192.168.6.128
192.168.6.129
192.168.6.130
192.168.6.131
192.168.6.132
192.168.6.133
192.168.6.134
192.168.6.135
192.168.6.0
192.168.6.1
192.168.6.2
192.168.6.3
192.168.6.4
192.168.6.5
192.168.6.6
192.168.6.7

This will be down one column on an alternate sheet.  I do want to thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
Public Sub GenerateIPRange()
'Establishes variables for each section of an IP Address
Dim x1, x2, x3, x4lower, x4upper As Long
'Prompts the user for each section of the IP Address.
x1 = InputBox("Enter a value for X: XXX.1.1.1", "Enter a value", "192")
x2 = InputBox("Enter a value for X: 1.XXX.1.1", "Enter a value", "168")
x3 = InputBox("Enter a value for X: 1.1.XXX.1", "Enter a value", "1")
x4lower = InputBox("Enter lowest value for X: 1.1.1.XXX", "Enter a value", "1")
x4upper = InputBox("Enter highest value for X: 1.1.1.XXX", "Enter a value", "10")


With Worksheets.Add   'Creates a new worksheet and continues to work with this new worksheet
    .Name = x1 & "." & x2 & "." & x3   'Renames the new worksheet to the first 3 digits of the IP
    Dim counter As Long 'A counter for sequencing cells
    counter = 1   'Starting at cell 1

    Do Until x4lower > x4upper   'A loop through all numbers requested from user
        .Cells(counter, 1) = x1 & "." & x2 & "." & x3 & "." & x4lower   'Enters the value into cell
        x4lower = x4lower + 1   'Increment the last digits of the IP
        counter = counter + 1   'Increment the cell counter (move down a cell)
    Loop   'Begin loop again if necessary
End With   'Stop working with the new worksheet

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is possible and quite simple assuming the Format is always the same.

I have assumed in your first sheet cell(1,1) i.e. A1 is the start of your values and it continues down the column for each new value if this is not the case then the code will not work. However if its not the case it would still be possible to find a solution you would just need to be able to provide a more detailed example of what you would get.

Putting the code below into a new module in your spread sheet should work a treat

```
Sub Help()

a = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
rowpos = 1

For i = 1 To a
    x1 = Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), 1, 3)
    x2 = Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), 5, 3)
    x3 = Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), 9, 1)
    x4 = Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), 13, 2)
    For j = 1 To x4
        Sheet2.Cells(rowpos, 1).Value = x1 & "." & x2 & "." & x3 & "." & j
        rowpos = rowpos + 1
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Something similar to above should completely automate your solution. I am always willing to help more if this does not quite work for your example however feel free to look into the functions I have used it should all be possible with these.

note - this assumes that the number of masks for each ip will always be a double digit value as in not less than 10 not more than 99

Darren